# File path not read correctly

Tags: python, keras

I'm new to DL and I'm going by a book to build my first CNN. The thing is (and I've tried various ways) i can't get the files to open a transfer a portion of the images into a smaller dataset. Below is the code and the error i get when i try to run my program. I've tried to change the backlashes in every way i can think of but i can't seem to get the program to check into the subfolder of the catsvdogs folder.

Code:

```
import os, shutil


# Path to the directory where the original DS was uncompressed

original_dir = 'datasets/catsvdogs'
# Directory to store my smaller dataset

base_dir = 'datasets/catsvdogs_small'
os.mkdir(base_dir)

# Directories for the training, validation, and test splits

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'valid')
os.mkdir(validation_dir)
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
os.mkdir(test_dir)

# Directory with training cat pictures

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

# Directory with training dog pictures 

train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(train_dogs_dir)

# Directory with validation cat pictures 

validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(validation_cats_dir)

# Directory with validation dog pictures

validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(validation_dogs_dir)

# Directory with test cat pictures

test_cats_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(test_cats_dir)

# Directory with test dog pictures

test_dogs_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'dogs')
os.mkdir(test_dogs_dir)

# Copying the first 1000 cat images to train_cats_dir

fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dir + 'train', fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

Error i get:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets/catsvdogstrain\\cat.0.jpg'
```

Comment: What system are you on, Windows?

Comment: @killian95 Yes i use Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think there are two issues:

1. You use Unix style slashes at first ('/') but you are on a windows system. So when you call os.path.join later, you also introduce windows style slashes ('\\'). That's why in your error message you see both types of slashes.

**To address this**: use os.path.join to create all strings that represent directories (see below)

2. In your 3rd to last line `src = os.path.join(original_dir + 'train', fname)`, you directly concatenate two strings rather than joining them with a slash. That's why you get `datasets/catsvdogstrain` in your error message instead of the expected 
   `datasets/catsvdogs/train`.

**To address this**: Join original_dir and 'train' with os.path.join (see below)

Here's how you can fix your code:

```
import os, shutil

# First, use os.path.join to reference your directories.
# That way you automatically pick the right "slash" (i.e. / or \\)
original_dir = os.path.join('datasets', 'catsvdogs')
base_dir = os.path.join('datasets', 'catsvdogs_small')

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

# Copying the first 1000 cat images to train_cats_dir
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:

    # This will make a filepath that looks like 'datasets/catsvdogs/train'
    # You directly joined two strings via original_dir + 'train' which
    # gave you 'datasets/catsvdogstrain' in your error message
    src_dir = os.path.join(original_dir, 'train')

    src = os.path.join(src_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)

    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```